# Scrolling cause flickering when controlling MouseWheel events

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

I'm trying to understand what is executing before the MouseWheel event.

What I've done:

- I have a form which has AutoScroll property set to true. There is a control (ZEDGRAPH) at the top and the bottom of this form.
- To overcome the issue of scrolling and zooming at the same time I captured the `mousewheel += new MouseEvenHandler(mymethod)` for the form.Then using a bool variable I keep track of when the control (ZEDGRAPH) has focus and when it does not.
- When it has focus I make `verticalscroll.value = (int)mydesiredposition;`

This works in accomplishing what I wanted which is to ignore the mousewheel event in the form and focus on the control. 
What I am struggling with is the fact that when I scroll the form flickers every time and scrolls down before coming to the set scrollbar value.

So what I am wondering is what is getting triggered before this mouseeventhandler that causes it to flicker and is there a relatively simple workaround this?

My code snapshot:

```
public Form(Form1 f)
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(mousewheel);
        }//end of constructor
        //
        //
        bool mousehoverZedGraph1 = false;
        bool mousehoverZedGraph2 = false;
        //
        //


 private void zedGraphControl1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            mousehoverZedGraph1 = true;
            return;
        }

private void mousewheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (mousehoverZedGraph1 == true)
            {
                VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
               VerticalScroll.Value = 0;

                return;

            }
            else if (mousehoverZedGraph2 == true)
            {
                VerticalScroll.Value = 429;
                VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //VerticalScroll.Value += e.Delta;
            }

        }

private void Form_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mousehoverZedGraph1 = mousehoverZedGraph2 = false;
            VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
        }
```

A small  [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkddT.jpg)  highlighting the flicker:

Comment: Override `OnMouseWheel` (instead of subcribing to the event): there you can write: `if (mousehoverZedGraph1 || mousehoverZedGraph2) return; base.OnMouseWheel(e);`. Set `mousehoverZedGraph1` & `2` to `true`/ `false` in the controls' `Enter` and `Leave` events (of course, removing the `zedGraphControl1_MouseHover` and `Form_MouseEnter` handlers).